# Is there any reason to prefer [[ over [ in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I used to think `[` would spawn `/usr/bin/test` and `[[` was a builtin, but apparently, it doesn't:

```
$ strace bash -c " [ -z "$FOO" ] && echo yes " 2>&1 | grep test
```

and

```
$ type [
[ is a shell builtin
```

`[` is a shorter and seems more portable too.
I'm on `GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).`

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031

Comment: Ok, so TL;DR: no, unless I'm using one of the special features of [[. Great link +1, @jasonwryan!

Comment: I think you misread the page: if your shebang is bash, you should always prefer `[[` over `[`.